# css solution to hide div after x amount of seconds

Tags: css

Any way using css3 only to remove/hide the #a after say 90 seconds of page load ?

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="box">
    <a id="hide_after_90_seconds"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

i would love to go from display:block to display:none if possible ?

Comment: Sounds more like a job to javascript to me... There could be an ugly workaround with `transition-delay` but I can't see how to make it work

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is possible with CSS animation and the `forwards` property to pause the animation at 100%. The `display` property cannot be animated.

The element is given `position: relative` and then `opacity: 0` and `left: -9999px` when it reaches 100%.  It will fade and then pull itself outside the viewport.

[See browser support here](http://caniuse.com/#search=keyframes) - Compatible IE 10+ !

[Here is a complete list of animated properties.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties)

Here are three ways to pull the div outside of the viewport at 100%:

1. `left: -9999px` combined with `position: relative` on the element (Like in the example below)
2. `height: 0` or `max-height: 0` combined with `text-indent: -9999px`
3. [This example with border-width](http://jsfiddle.net/troygizzi/2d4ar7jr/) from [@Troy Gizzi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3212415/troy-gizzi)

### Example

This example fades the text after 5 seconds and then removes the div from the viewport.

```css
div {
  -webkit-animation: seconds 1.0s forwards;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
  animation: seconds 1.0s forwards;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-delay: 5s;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
}
@-webkit-keyframes seconds {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    left: -9999px; 
  }
}
@keyframes seconds {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    left: -9999px; 
  }
}
```

```html
<div>hide me after 5 seconds</div>
```

Comment: It's good to note that CSS3 animation does not support tweening between `display: block` and `display: none`. If the OP really has to go this route, JS is the only solution.

Comment: would it be possible to scale the div height to 0 ? since display:none would not work ?

Comment: @MShack Unfortunately CSS animation also does not support tweening between `height: auto` and `height: 0`, which is a real shame :(

Comment: +1 even though you broke protocol by posting a CSS-only solution that _even works in IE_. Nobody does that! :-)

Comment: @MShack - Use `position: relative` on the div and then `left: -9999px; ` at 100%. That will remove the div completely from the viewport after it fades.

Comment: @TroyGizzi - I am amazed IE10+ supports animation. I never use it,  but I should!

Comment: left:-9999px did not remove the div , it still takes up the space on the page :(

Comment: @MShack - have you got `position: relative` on the element it self? `position: relative` cannot be in the keyframes... Does it look exactly like my example?

Comment: Just for kicks: A [CSS-only countdown](http://jsfiddle.net/troygizzi/mcLwhxnu/)! :-D ...but oh, the ugliness when scaled to 90 seconds instead of just 3...

Comment: i was able to get it working by using max-height:500 and then in keyframes setting to max-height:0   TY guys !

Comment: @MShack - In that case, you might also want to place `text-indent: -9999px;` at 100%. Removing all height will remove the div, but not any text. `text-indent: -9999px;` can do that for you.

Comment: Here's an alternate stab at removing the empty gap left behind, using border-width-bottom: http://jsfiddle.net/troygizzi/2d4ar7jr/ -- but it seems to be a bit flaky in IE; it works after I click Run, but not when the page is first loaded. Not sure if that's just a JSFiddle issue or what...

Comment: Follow-up on the IE oddity: It works fine when loaded as a normal web page. Must just be a JSFiddle quirk.

Comment: @TroyGizzi - Yeah, the fiddle has no problems for me in Chrome. I added the link with your name in the answer :)

Answer (score 9):

```css
#hidethis { animation: css 0s 3s forwards; }

@keyframes css  { to { visibility: hidden; } }
                    /* visibility / overflow: hidden; */
```

```html
<div id='hidethis'>Wait for 3 seconds...</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Closest you can come with css only is this..it might be improved further but this as it's..

http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/7g7ofazj/

```
.red {
    background-color: red; width: 100px; height: 100px;
    -webkit-animation: ani 1s forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes ani {
    89%  {opacity:1;height: 100px;}
    90%  {opacity:0; height: 0;}
    100%  {opacity:0; height: 0;}
}
```

And if you wanted to do with javascript/jquery..

you would do this..

```
var ele = $(".hide_after_90_seconds");
setTimeout(function() { ele.hide(); }, 9000);
```

Comment: For the timing, I'm sure you mean `90000`? `900` is only 0.9s :)

Comment: Your shared url http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/7g7ofazj/  is showing error "404 That page doesn't exist." Please update or remove it from here.

Comment: no, that's the nature of urls. they get deleted overtime, that's why SO requires code to be put in the answer as I've. Not sure why would i update 7 years old answer.