# How to hide an loading screen before the animation goes out

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating an website and I am really new in this area.
So, while i was coding, i had a question:
How do I hide an element after an animation goes out?
Per example:
This is my body:

```
<div id="loader">
    <div id="box"></div>
    <div id="hill"></div>
</div>
```

and the css is pretty big, and i uploaded in pastebin because i think there is better to read.
https://pastebin.com/UU38K4Wf

What i want to do is show the text, images, and etc AFTER the animation dissapear.
How do i do that?

Sorry for the bad english, still learning...

Answer (score 0):

You can use visibility: hidden; in your css.

Comment: but when i put it in my code, the animation doesn't even shows in the page. (i'm new on this so sorry if it's simple to solve)

Comment: You may find your solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26393539/css-solution-to-hide-div-after-x-amount-of-seconds)

Answer (score 0):

`visibility: hidden;` good option.Any way first You add an attribute in your div tag `display:none` and take `div id` name,after find where the loader call happen and use `div id name` like

It's for show the hidden div `idname.attribute.add("display:");` or `idname.show();` and 
this one for hide `div`  `idname.attribute.add("display:none");` or `idname.hide();`

I think it will work.